# Scrapy: Scraping CSV File - not getting any output

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I am following this example: [CSVFeedSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CSVFeedSpider) to scrape CSV data, 'item.xml' is generated but there's nothing in the xml file.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

**csvspider.py**

```
class MySpider(CSVFeedSpider):
    name = 'csvexample'
    start_urls = ['file:///D:/desktop/example.csv']
    delimiter = ','
    headers = ['Address', 'Website']

    def parse_row(self, response, row):
        log.msg('Hi, this is a row!: %r' % row)
        item = csvItems()
        item['address'] = row['Address']
        item['website'] = row['Website']
        return item
```

**items.py**

```
class csvItems(Item):
    address = Field()
    website = Field()
```

**example.csv**

```
Item,Address,Website
1,"this, address","www.google.com"
```

**commands used to run**

```
scrapy crawl csvexample -o item.xml -t xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the spider by itself, without the output parameters, then you would probably see errors similar to the following:

```
2014-05-12 08:08:41+0100 [scrapy] WARNING: ignoring row 1 (length: 3, should be: 2)
2014-05-12 08:08:41+0100 [scrapy] WARNING: ignoring row 2 (length: 3, should be: 2)
```

To fix the issue, modify your headers line in your spider code as follows:

```
headers = ['Item', 'Address', 'Website']
```

Comment: Thanks!! this works. So, the key is that the headers array should be the same length as the number of columns in the CSV file.

Comment: Exactly that. I suspected as much when I saw the example csv file, but ran the spider code to confirm my hypothesis. 

Scrapy gives reasonably lucid error messages, so it's always worth checking the logs after running the spider to see if any errors are occurring that may explain missing data or what have you. :)