# Getting Error while using CSVFeedSpider

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I am using **`CSVFeedSpider`** for scraping a local csv file (foods.csv).

Here it is:

```
calories    name                         price

650         Belgian Waffles              $5.95

900         Strawberry Belgian Waffles   $7.95

900         Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles  $8.95

600         French Toast                 $4.50

950         Homestyle Breakfast          $6.95
```

Here is my code for **foods.py** file:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CSVFeedSpider
from foods_csv.items import FoodsCsvItem

class FoodsSpider(CSVFeedSpider):
    name = 'foods'
    start_urls = ['file:///users/Mina/Desktop/foods.csv']
    delimiter = ';'
    quotechar = "'"
    headers = ['name', 'price', 'calories']

    def parse_row(self, response, row):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is a row!: %r', row)
        item = FoodsCsvItem()
        item['name'] = row['name']
        item['price'] = row['price']
        item['calories'] = row['calories']
        return item
```

**items.py**:

```
import scrapy

class FoodsCsvItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    calories = scrapy.Field()
```

but it gives me this error:

```
2017-11-18 13:04:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///users/Mina/Desktop/foods.csv> (referer: None)
2017-11-18 13:04:26 [scrapy.utils.iterators] WARNING: ignoring row 1 (length: 1, should be: 3)
2017-11-18 13:04:26 [scrapy.utils.iterators] WARNING: ignoring row 2 (length: 1, should be: 3)
2017-11-18 13:04:26 [scrapy.utils.iterators] WARNING: ignoring row 3 (length: 1, should be: 3)
2017-11-18 13:04:26 [scrapy.utils.iterators] WARNING: ignoring row 4 (length: 1, should be: 3)
2017-11-18 13:04:26 [scrapy.utils.iterators] WARNING: ignoring row 5 (length: 1, should be: 3)
2017-11-18 13:04:26 [scrapy.utils.iterators] WARNING: ignoring row 6 (length: 1, should be: 3)
```

At the beginning I was only scraping 'name' and 'price' but it gave me the same error so I tried to add 'calories' according to this solution [Scrapy: Scraping CSV File - not getting any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602554/scrapy-scraping-csv-file-not-getting-any-output) but nothing changed!

I only need to scrape 'name' and 'price' how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like possibly the exact format of your CSV-file got lost when posting it. If the formatting is exactly as posted here, then it actually looks like a TSV (Tab Separated Values) file, and you could try to change the `delimiter = ';'` to `delimiter = '\t'`.

However, since you have specified `'` as quote character I assume this is correct? I would try to run a search/replace on the CSV file and replace `'` with `"` and see if that helps. I've had some weird issues before using the single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   def parse_row(self, response, row):
       self.logger.info('Hi, this is a row!: %r', row)
       item = FoodsCsvItem()
       item['name'] = row['name']
       item['price'] = row['price']
       item['calories'] = row['calories']
       return item
```